# Disable set aside tabs in Edge

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

The Creator's update added a new feature to Edge called "setting aside tabs". While it sounds nice, I really don't need it and it is actually creating problems for me. While clicking on the first tab in the list, I often accidentally click on the set aside button and all tabs have to be reloaded again.

Is there some switch to disable this new feature?

Answer (score 4):

The official answer by Microsoft to this question can be found in their forum
post
[How to turn off "set these tabs aside" in Edge on Win10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/how-to-turn-off-set-these-tabs-aside-in-edge-on/7d0b03bd-6914-4086-8bdf-eb42247c96aa?auth=1).
The count of "I have the same question" on this post is 90.

Dyan Rey from Microsoft replied on July 20, 2017 :

> Disabling “set these tabs aside” is not yet possible in Microsoft
>   Edge. Your feedback helps to continually improve your experience with
>   our product.
>
> Here are the steps on how to submit a feedback:
>
> 1. On your Windows 10 device, search for Feedback Hub in the Cortana Search box, and launch the application.
> 2. Navigate to Feedback in the left menu, then press + Add new feedback.
> 3. Select the Problem, share any details you think are relevant, and choose an appropriate category and subcategory.
> 4. Important: If possible, reproduce the issue after clicking Begin monitoring (or Start capture) near the end of the form; Stop
>      monitoring when you are done.
> 5. Once you have completed the form and monitoring, click Submit.
> 6. Click Continue using Feedback Hub.
> 7. Click My feedback at the top, and find the item you submitted (it may take a while to appear).
> 8. Open the item you submitted, then click Share.
> 9. Click Copy link, then paste the link here in your response (it will look like https://aka.ms\ link>)

I found this link mentioned : `https://aka.ms/B6urh8`, but I'm unwilling
to sign on to the Feedback app to verify it.

Other answers by Microsoft that say the same :

- [Recent Edge update "Set aside tabs" created problems](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/msedge/recent-edge-update-set-aside-tabs-created-problems/7355c585-592c-4ec6-ac8c-0705e113c52b) (August 1, 2017)
- [Disabling Set Aside Tabs in Edge on Win10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/disabling-set-aside-tabs-in-edge-on-win10/fa5290b8-9139-4ed3-8667-da4bf4fdb382) (June 19, 2017)

I am afraid that all you can do at the moment is join your voice to the
feedback channel, and wait for Microsoft to act.
As far as I know, there are actually no non-Microsoft workarounds or hacks.

Comment: Can you please look again? Has anything changed since your post?

Comment: @gparyani: The only thing that has changed is that the count of "I have the same question" on the above linked post is now 265. A [new post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-win_desk/how-do-i-turn-off-the-save-tabs-feature-in-edge/01337b05-4303-4d9d-98fa-d459595dd3d4) from March 31, 2018, has the same answer.